# String modifying in python; \ and " causing problems

Tags: python, regex, string

Process:

1. Reading .csv from a blackbox
2. Modifying it's contents
3. Saving it to JSON
4. Sending it back to blackbox

I've done it in a following way:

```
  with open (argv[1], "r", encoding="utf-8") as inFile:
      csv.register_dialect('beenix', delimiter = ';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
      csvRead = csv.reader(inFile, dialect='beenix') 
      newList = []
    for line in csvRead:
        tempString = str(line)
        tempString = tempString.replace(" / ", ",")
        tempString = tempString.replace("\'", "")
        tempString = tempString.replace("\\\"", "") # doesn't work
        tempString = tempString.replace("[", "")
        tempString = tempString.replace("]", "")
        re.sub(r'[\"]', "", tempString) # doesn't work
        parts = tempString.split(",")
        tempDict = {"district": parts[2], "quotient": float(parts[4].strip()), "party": parts[1],"votes": int(parts[3].strip()), "name": parts[0]}
        newList.append(tempDict)
  with open (argv[2], "w", encoding="utf-8") as outFile:
      json.dump(newList, outFile, indent=3)
```

So, problem being, that I don't seem to be able to delete "\"" (\ and "-sequences) from the strings.
The following methods has been tried:

```
tempString.replace("\\\"", "")

re.sub(r'[\"]', "", tempString)
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: why do you convert the `line` (which is a `list`) to a string in the first place?

Comment: `s = s.replace("\\\"", "")` this works for me. Try printing out the string before and after the replace. This is probably not the cause of your problem.

Comment: I have a hunch your string is not exactly what you expect after you convert it. Did you print your string after `str(line)` to check? If you are getting that sequence it will probably be represented as `\\"` (only escapes the backslash) in `tempString`.

Comment: Double from below:
This being Uni work, I' not able to do that, since I can't access the second input.txt, which is used in testing.

Consensus seems to be, that methods are in right format, so I'm going to contact the lecturer about possible bug in their end.. Seems reasonable, since I/we can't debug this any further..

Answer (score 3):

This is a XY problem.

You *don't have to convert a list to its string representation*, then remove the quoting, the separators, the brackets...

That's a very bad idea, this since `csv` module provides the data in the format you want without any effort:

```
for parts in csvRead:
```

at this point `parts` is a list containing your row data, without any quotes or escape chars.

(ok it doesn't answer the replacement questions, but it solves your problem in a much better way)

note: if after having decoded the fields, you *really* want to replace some remaining backslashes by nothing, it's simple, just don't overdo it:

```
>>> foo = r"a\b"
>>> foo.replace("\\","")
'ab'
```

same goes for double quotes. Avoid the escaping by using the alternate quoting:

```
>>> foo = 'a"b'
>>> foo.replace('"',"")
'ab'
```

Comment: Yea, thanks for pointing that out. 

Although, there's still \"-sequences in parts of the strings (namely name-parts), which wouldn't get fixed that way.
I'm starting to think, that there might be something iffy going on in the blackbox.

Comment: try to print the fields, you'll see that there aren't any backquotes in the decoded data. `csv` module handles that. of course if you print the row you'll get a representation of the data with backslashes, but strings don't contains them.

Comment: This being Uni work, I' not able to do that, since I can't access the second input.txt, which is used in testing.

Consensus seems to be, that methods are in right format, so I'm going to contact the lecturer about possible bug in their end.

Comment: can you post your input as text in your question?

Comment: Only output: 

    -      "district": "Pirkanmaan vaalipiiri\""
    +      "district": "Pirkanmaan vaalipiiri"

Difference being \" in the end of the minus marked expression.

Comment: there's an extra quote & probably extra backslash. Use the replace commands at the end of my answer on the relevant `parts[i]` to strip them off. But the input is corrupt. Those chars shouldn't be in input.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
tempString = tempString.replace(r'\"', '')
```

The prepended `r` before the string makes it a [raw string](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html), so basically what you see between the quotes is what you get (no need to escape special characters). I enclosed with single quotes to make the distinction between the quotation mark you want to match and the quotes defining the string obvious.

If you want to use regex, you need to compile your pattern (and also change your pattern slightly):

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\\"')  # note two back-slashes, not positive why...
new_str = re.sub(pattern, '', temp_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace it by

```
tempString = 'This [is] a test \"  asd \" '
tempString = tempString.replace('\"', "") 

print tempString
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Jean's answer, but according to your comment there the format still wasn't right?, so:

As I understood, and since this `tempString.replace("\\\"", "")` was something you tried, the thing is that your string contains sequences of literally `\\\"` (which would show in a print(your_string) as `\"`, or as`\\"` if you just write `your_string` to the console instead of using print) that you want to replace or eliminate, if so: (added various forms of backslash and quotes to show exactly what the substitution will and will not replace)

```
>>> import re
>>> example = "text \n \" \"\"\"\" \\ \\\"  \\\"\\\" text"
>>> example
'text \n " """" \\ \\"  \\"\\" text'
>>> result = re.sub(r'(\\\")+', 'POOF', example)
>>> result
'text \n " """" \\ POOF  POOF text'
```

Unless you also wanted to replace those escaped double quotes that look like `" """"` when writing `result` to the console or printing:

```
>>> result2 = re.sub(r'\"+', 'Quotes-were-here', result)
>>> result2
'text \n Quotes-were-here Quotes-were-here \\ POOF  POOF text'
```

I wrote "POOF" and such to make what was being replaced for what clearer here, but you could as well just put an empty string there.

For the first result what's happening is: The `\\\"` of the regex means escaped-backslash concatenated with escaped-doubleQuotes, the parenthesis means that I want to group them together and have the regex match the regular expression as a whole, then the `+` means to match one or more of those groups. (EDIT: Alternatively, `r'\\\"'` alone also works, in which case it'd read "POOF POOFPOOF" in the result, I guess I thought of the one with the `+` sign because that was the first translation I thought of for "one or more of this sequence of characters" )

For the second one, it's just the escaped-doubleQuotes alone, which read as a single character (just like '\n'), so no need for parenthesis before the `+`.